# Datepicker is not show current date in magento grid module

Tags: magento-1.9, date

Here is my code :

```
$not_allowed_date=$fieldset->addField('not_allowed_date', 'date', array(
        'name'      => 'not_allowed_date',
        'label'     => Mage::helper('po')->__('Not Allowed Date'),
        'required'  => true,
        'image'  => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
        'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
        'note' => "dd-mm-yyyy",
        'time' => true
    ));
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to set date format as per your current locale

```
$dateFormatIso = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT);
        $fieldset->addField('not_allowed_date', 'date', array(
            'name'   => 'not_allowed_date',
            'label'  => Mage::helper('po')->__('Not Allowed Date'),
            'title'  => Mage::helper('po')->__('Not Allowed Date'),
            'image'  => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
            'input_format' => Varien_Date::DATE_INTERNAL_FORMAT,
            'value' => date('d/m/Y'),
            'format'       => $dateFormatIso
        ));
```

Comment: this code is not work in my grid module. My Problem is not solve. I am new in magento.

Answer (score 1):

> To Display Current Date in date picker you need to set date in value
>   parameter

```
    $fieldset->addField('not_allowed_date', 'date', array(
               'name'      => 'not_allowed_date',
               'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Not Allowed Date'),
               'required'  => true,
               'image'  => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
               'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
               'note' => "dd-mm-yyyy",
               'time' => true ,
               'value' => date('d/m/Y')
               )
   );
```

Comment: this code is not work in my grid module. My Problem is not solve. I am new in magento.

Comment: well you have added screen shot of form not grid

Comment: clear your magento cache. it should work in form

Comment: Hello sir, I want to show current date when select drop down list in "Not Allowed"  options. But it show 30-11-2000. Please solve my Problem. Thanks

Comment: I have clear all catch in magento but not work.